# FBA configuration with 2 AD in SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, web-application-zones

I have created Claim based SharePoint site for Form-based authentication.
The site is perfectly working with 1 Active Directory membership.

I need to add `2 AD membership` in the same SharePoint site. So both AD users can login with the same SharePoint site.

I know about `web application extension with different zone`. But my requirement is that URL should not be changed for both AD users.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean by "2 AD Membership" that users from two different ADs should be able to logon to your SharePoint Site.

You could use ADFS with the two domains as identity providers.
Users logon to ADFS and ADFS sends the claims to SharePoint. 
Based on those claims you can give users permissions or not.
I think the two ADs would need a two-way-trust to get this working.

We didn't run this configuration with FBA.
And I think it would be a major architectural change for you. It even means to reimport users in the User Profile Service..

We used LDAPCP as a Claims Provider to enhance the people picker search experience: https://ldapcp.com/